# How can I get Enterprise Manager for Oracle 11g R1 to install?

Tags: oracle11g, windows-xp, oracle-enterprise-manager

I am running a windows xp sp3 machine with 22gb free space, 1.5ghz Intel Pentium M and 768MB of RAM. Every time i try to install oracle 11g, the installation goes okay except for running the emca script.

> Enterprise manager failed due to the
>   following error- error starting
>   database control

caused by OracleDBConsoleorcl not being able to start

> Could not start the
>   OracleDBConsoleorcl on local computer.
>   Error 1053: The service did not
>   respond to the start or control
>   request in timely fashion.

the event logs show

> The OracleDBConsoleorcl service
>   terminiated with service-specific
>   error 2(0x2)

I have tried everything from editing the host file, setting a static ip to configuring the loopback adapter. None of this seems to be working. Is there something i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution:

1. do a normal install and ignore this message, if you see it:

> Enterprise manager failed due to the following error- error starting database control

2. setup up static IP, preferably on a loopback adapter if you are using a laptop, and make sure it is listed in host file as first IP O recommend using [HostExpert](http://www.funkytoad.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13) from funkytoad for this.
3. run the following at a command prompt (cmd as opposed to the run/open)

   ```
   set oracle_sid=orcl
   emca -repos recreate
   emca start dbconsole
   ```

and you should be good to go. In my case, Enterprise Manager is on port 1158 as opposed to 5500 so your mileage may vary.

Comment: The last line should be `emctl start dbconsole` (not emca, and dbconole without a typo), shouldn't it?